# Express validator isLength pass undefined value

Tags: express, express-validator

I am new to MERN Stack and I am following a course. I have encounter this problem that the value is undefined from the validator.

I am using `"express-validator": "^6.14.2"` from NPM.

```
router.post(
  "/signup",
  [
   check("name").not().isEmpty(),
   check("email").normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
   check("password").isLength({ min: 6 }),
 ],
 signup
);
```

**Postman request**

```
{
"name":"test 2",
"email":"test2@test.com",
"password:":"test123456",
"places":1
}
```

Changing the value of name from the postman is gives me the proper value that is an empty string, but the password is gives me an undefine value see picture below

[image]

I have also tried this  `check("password").not().isEmpty().isLength({ min: 6 }),`
but still it gives me the same problem value is undefined

Comment: Check your colons.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you. I was to focus on express side and did not focus from the request value of postman.